# MYSQL need help pulling data from each "user" using php

Tags: php, mysql, database

Here's what I have. This code grabs the data from all of the users and subtracts 1 from user_days then updates every user's user_days row.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $minusone = $row['user_days']-1;
  mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET user_days=$minusone");
  echo "<br />";
  echo $row['user_days'];
  }
```

The problem I'm having is this:
Instead of subtracting 1 from each user and updating each users field,
it's updating each user's field with the value from the first user.

example:
before updating
user 1 has 30 days
user 2 has 60 days

after updating
user 1 has 29 days
user 2 has 29 days (instead of 59 days)

Any help is appreciated and I hope this question is easy to understand.

Just to clarify, I DO want to update every field.
I just don't want the updates to be duplicated from the first result.

Thanks for all of the answers, this has given me a lot of help.

Comment: your SQL query updates all records. you should specify some condition into it, for example: `update users set user_days=$minusone where id= ` . `$row[id]` or whatever. Moreover, you do not need to do that in the loop. Try something like `update users set user_days=user_days-1;` standalone.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just run `UPDATE users SET user_days = user_days-1 WHERE id=XXXXX`? And then select the whole thing?

Comment: If it's being done for all users, why execute n times for each individual user, and not simply run it once for all users?

Answer (score 0):

When you update your record, you need to specify the user id for the record of interest, otherwise you current query updates all the rows in your table.

Comment: Or even simpler, use `UPDATE users SET user_days=user_days-1` before doing your select

Answer (score 0):

You should point which record to UPDATE

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET user_days=$minusone WHERE id=XXXXX");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `UPDATE` statement.  Without a `WHERE` clause it will apply the `SET` clause to every row in the database.  Assuming you have a unique id column named `id` in the users table, you could modify your code like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $minusone = $row['user_days']-1;
  $user_id = $row['id'];
  mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET user_days=$minusone WHERE id=$user_id");
  echo "<br />";
  echo $row['user_days'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Query:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET user_days=$minusone WHERE user_ID = '".$row['user_ID']."'");
```

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Answer (score 0):

You're updating all the users with the same `$minusone` value. You need a `WHERE` clause in your update statement, like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $minusone = $row['user_days']-1;
  $id_user = $row['id_user'];
  mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET user_days=$minusone WHERE id_user = $id_user");
  echo "<br />";
  echo $row['user_days'];
  }
```

Another way of doing what you want would be:

```
...
$result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET user_days = user_days - 1");
...
```

This assuming you want to substracts 1 to all `user_days`.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by other answers, the best way to do this is to replace your entire code block with one line.

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET user_days=user_days-1");
```

Then you can SELECT and display the information as needed.

Without knowing exactly what you are using `user_days` for, I'm thinking there may be a better approach to what you are trying to do. I am assuming this is some kind of subscription service, and this code will be run once per day to decrement the number of days to allow them to access the service.

A better approach would be to have a `subscriptionExpires` field in your database, which would hold a datetime value. Using your approach, if the job that runs this fails, every user will get an extra day. What if a web spider or a user finds your script, your users accounts will expire early. If you use an actual date for when the account expires, there's no guessing if the current value is correct.